# How to fix a mirrored GML file in ArcMap (Latitude & Longitude values reversed)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, gml, data-interoperability

I want to import [this](http://hmbtg.geronimus.info/geoserver/ows?request=getfeature&service=WFS&typename=HmbTG_Basis_Gewaessernetz_FHH) file into ArcMap 10.4. 
On the page it says it's a csv, when downloaded it's a .text-file. I renamed it to GML, as they usually have GML on that platform, and the file content looks like GML to me.

Using Add Data in Arc Map (Data Interoperability Extension is activated), i get a mirrored version of the data, with no spatial reference.

[image]

It's supposed to look look like [this](http://www.geoportal-hamburg.de/Geoportal/geo-online/?mdid=87D410AB-2567-4E29-AC91-62A9DD0ECDF4#).

How do I fix this?

Comment: The page you are referring to is http://suche.transparenz.hamburg.de/dataset/basis-gewassernetz-fur-hamburg2 ? Yeah, it's GML, not CSV. Make sure you use the correct CRS, it is EPSG:3044

Comment: I made a new Projekt, and changed the data frame CRS to ETRS_1989_ETRS-TM32 (which is supposedly EPSG:3044). Then i added the GML via Add Data. It still displays at the same off position, somewhere off the coast of Somalia... am I doing something wrong? I also tried exporting to a new shpfile, and setting the CRS in Arc Catalog to ETRS_1989_ETRS-TM32 once again, still the same position.

Comment: I found the problem in the file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in the GML file.

The Lat/Lon float values were in the wrong order, so each latitude value was interpreted as longitude and vice versa.

I wrote a regular expression, to switch the values and applied it to the GML with Notepad++.

This is the Regular expression. May it be a help to anyone, who finds this:

- Find: `([-]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s([-]*[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)`
- Replace with: `\2 \1`

Using Replace Dialog in Notepad++ to apply the regular expression to the GML file:
[image: Using Replace Dialog in Notepad++ to apply the regular expression to the GML file.]

Example of what it does:

- given:`5939544.160688 576255.677226`
- result:`576255.677226 5939544.160688`

Now the file can be imported into the GIS.
If the coordinates are comma seperated, just replace the \s with a comma.